# How to make the bottom toolbar float just above on the soft keyboard when the Textfield get focus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

[image]I add a toolbar in bottom of UIViewController and put a TextField on the toolbar, but when I hit the TextField ,the textfield is covered by popup-ed soft keyboard and Can't see it.

So, How to float the toolbar just above on the soft keyboard when the Textfield get focus.

Comment: just position up you toolbar in textFieldshould begin editing and down when endediting

Comment: set the frame of toolbar in UItextField delegate method textFiledBeginEditing

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called **inputAccessoryView**. When a textField is tapped you can call it like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    textField.inputAccessoryView=self.accessoryToolBar;


    return YES;

}
```

this will call the toolbar on top of your keyboard.

Comment: I added below code, but when I tap the TextField , the toolbar and keyboard both are disappeard.
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.inputAccessoryView=self.bottomBar;
    return YES;
}

Comment: you have to make sure that your accessoryToolBar is linked via an outlet. Otherwise your viewControler doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: Yes I have linked the toolbar to view controller by outlet.

Comment: make sure you have the UITextFieldDelegate included on you viewController.

Comment: Here, I created a small project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21592548/AccessoryView.zip

Comment: Hi,Marcal, thanks for the kindly help, yes with your project it works. But in my case I put the TextFiled into the UIToolBar and on the bottom of view. Don't know why it not work in this case. I eidt the question with of a picture , Can you help to have a look, thanks!

Comment: please check all the code on the project I did. You have to reference the textField also with an outlet and set its delegate to self on viewDidLoad, for example.

Comment: Yes I did. Now when I tap the textfield , the keyboard not show and toolbar disappeared